# Is the object a pulsar

Tags: black-hole, neutron-star, white-dwarf

> We have a star having 1.8 solar mass. Justify any four means (measurable/ observed properties) by which you can identify that the object is a Pulsar and not a white dwarf or a Black Hole.

So one obvious property would be the mass. Since mass > 1.4 solar mass, we can say it is not a white dwarf.

Also the mass is less than 3 solar mass, hence its not a black hole (I'm speaking loosely over here).

Also from periodic radiation patterns, we can say that the object might be a pulsar.

I need help with 2 other means to categorize this object.

Comment: Being a homework question is neither bad nor good, we could recommend how the question could be improved though. Also see [Make no prior research or effort a reason to close?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/428/7982)

Comment: Please note that many students are being asked to do "at home", uninvigilated exams right now. Please do not answer such questions.

Comment: This is not an exam, just some assignment, and I am not a school going kid.

Answer (score 1):

1. As you said, the mass range of the object indicates that it could be a neutron star, rather than a black hole.
2. But also the density of the object is a clue. The density of a neutron star is much higher than that of a stable white dwarf.
3. Extremely regular electromagnetic pulses have to be observed. Known pulsars have a pulse period between 1.4 ms and 8.5 seconds.
4. The wavelength of the pulses is in the radio range.
5. Pulsars slow down gradually, at a known rate, so you can measure how the pulse period evolves over time, and check that is compatible with the slow-down rate of a pulsar.

Adapted from [this page](https://www.cv.nrao.edu/course/astr534/Pulsars.html)